# mysql ignore any distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

i am trying to run a sql query which will not show distinct/duplicate values.

For example if using distinct option it would display only one unique result, but i would like to skip all detected distinct values i.e dont display distinct values

is it possible?

```
    select col1  d from tb_col  where col1 = '123';

col1
------
123
123


(2 rows)


select distinct col1  d from tb_col  where col1 = '123';

col1
------
123
(1 row)
```

Comment: So you want your query to ignore duplicates completely, rather than trying to "merge" them?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to see results where the count of a specific field is 1?

Comment: can you also post the desired result? It is not very clear what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not showing duplicates at all:

```
SELECT col1 AS d
FROM tb_col
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1            --- or perhaps HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                               --- it's not clear what you want.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT col1 
FROM tb_col 
GROUP BY col1 
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Comment: `as d` display the column with the label `d` instead of `col1`, no difference what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select col1
  from tb_col
  group by col1
  having count(*) < 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with **DISTINCT** it will works!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(col1) as d from tb_col  where col1 = '123';
```

Comment: This is exactly the OP's second query. Well, without the parenthesis.

Comment: The OP's requirements is, the values that have duplicates must be omitted entirely.